# No visible @interface when trying to call a Swift method in objective c

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to call a Swift method in objective c:

```
func checkItem(atIndex:Int) -> Bool {
    print("Hard work")
    return false;
}
```

But I get the error: 
`No visible @interface for 'RateAppViewPagerHelper' declares the selector 'checkItem:'`

The objective c code call is:

```
[finder checkItem:_index];
```

What do I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: what about `[finder checkItemAtIndex:_index]`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method signature will be `checkItemAtIndex:` instead of `checkItem` because of the external label on the parameter in the swift method.